# Deciphering a proof that $\delta_0 \not\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

The following is an excerpt from the class notes for my PDEs class
[image]

Does anyone know how exactly the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem could have been applied here? My first instinct is to cry out in agony. Isn't the Lebesgue theorem only applicable in L1?  In the actual working of the question from class, this is a complete transcription of what the professor did:

\begin{align} ||\phi_n - u_n||_{L^2}^2 &= ||\phi_n -\phi_n +\eta_n\phi_n||_{L^2}^2 \\ &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \eta_n^2(x)\phi_n(x) dx \\ &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \eta_n^2||\phi_n - \delta_0 + \delta_0||^2 \\ & \leq 2 \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \eta_n^2(\phi_n - \delta_0)^2 dx + 2\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\eta_n^2\delta_0^2(x)dx&  \\ & \qquad \downarrow \qquad\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \downarrow \text{Apply Lebesgue Dom. Con.}\\ & \qquad \ 0 \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad\ \ \ 0 \end{align}
I'm completely lost as to trying to parse what the professor did, to the point where I'm not sure if I'm lost, or if he has made a mistake somewhere?

Edit: In the class notes, $\eta_n$ was given as a $\left( \overline{B(0,\frac{1}{n})},B(0,\frac{2}{n})\right)$ cutoff function

Comment: Note that if $\eta_n \delta_0 \in L^2$ then $\eta_n^2 \delta_0^2 \in L^1$. Apply LDC to this last sequence of $L^1$ functions.

Comment: @N.S. So, LDC gives that if $\eta_n^2\delta_0^2 \in L^{1}$, where  $\eta_n^2\delta_0^2 \to f(x)$, and $\eta_n^2\delta_0^2 \leq g(x) \in L^1$,  then $||\eta_n^2\delta_0^2 - f(x)||_{L^1} \to 0$. Is the idea that the $f(x)$ in this case would just be $0$, so $||\eta_n^2\delta_0^2||_{L^1} \to 0$? I feel like there's some assumed knowledge regarding the behaviour of the cutoff function that I'm missing here.

Comment: Yes, $f(x)=0$. Note that $\eta_n^2 \delta_0^2 \leq \delta_0^2 \in L^1$ and $\eta_n =0$ outside $B(0, \frac{1}{n})$. Therefore $\eta_n^2 \delta_0^2 =0$ outside this ball, and hence $\eta_n^2 \delta_0^2(x)$ converges to $0$ for all $x \neq 0$, i.e. almost everywhere.

Comment: @N.S. Thanks so much, you're a life saver.

Comment: You are welcome. Note that with the Edit, $\eta_n^2 \delta_0$ becomes $0$ outside $B(0, \frac{2}{n})$, but this makes no difference to the argument.